# Suppressing Severity Level 10 Messages SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to suppress severity level 10 messages (e.g. Job 'Job' stopped successfully.). No, `SET NOCOUNT ON` and `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` do not work.

The issue is once a specific action is done, on the user side, if a specific job is running it needs to stop. Once the job is stopped successfully the message is coming up as an ODBC error and I need this to not happen. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Severity 10 should not be showing up as an error. Double check that there aren't more error records that the innocuous "job stopped" message is rolled into. You can also try a manual `RAISERROR('Hello, world!', 10, 0)` as the sole statement to confirm or deny that a severity 10 message is a problem -- if it is, I'd say that's an error on the client side by failing to [follow the rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-error-messages/handling-errors-and-messages). (And no, I'm not aware of any way to suppress informational messages from the T-SQL side.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I will look into that. This and exmaple of the "error" message that they are getting [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Job 'xp_cmdshell replacement - 2018-07-03 10:35:07.253pulse' stopped successfully.

Comment: I'm not sure what client software formats things like that -- other than `bcp`, perhaps -- but that's not an error, no. If you try `RAISERROR('Bad, bad world!', 11, 1)`, you can see how it formats an actual error -- I'm betting it'll have "error" somewhere in there. The whole `[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]` bit is put there by the client; only `Job 'xp_cmdshell replacement - 2018-07-03 10:35:07.253pulse' stopped successfully.` is what's actually sent by SQL Server, so you may be able to fix things by parsing the result.

Comment: The message that they are getting pops up as a .txt called ODBCERROR.txt. That is why I am calling it an error, not because there was an actual error (sorry for the confusion). I tried doing both `RAISERROR('Hello, world!', 10, 0)` and `RAISERROR('Bad, bad world!', 11, 1)` and I got the same "error" messages.

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Hello, world!

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Bad, bad world!

Comment: That's painful. :-P I think your only recourse may be to apply after the fact filtering with some regexes/wildcards, so "errors" like `.*stopped successfully.*` are filtered out as the informational messages they are. In other words, everything is an error unless proven innocent. Like I said before, as far as I know you can't make the server stop sending these (and you can't modify `sp_stop_job`, obviously). Either that, or find better client software that properly distinguishes between informational diagnostic records and actual errors.

Comment: Unfortunately a new client software is not an option. Thanks for all your help!